# React redirects in dev but not in build

Tags: reactjs, netlify

Due to some poor planning and some problems with domain registration I'm building a quick react app that's only function is to redirect to another site when the page loads. To do this I created a component like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.location.replace("insert url here");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This method works perfectly when in development, but does not perform the redirect when the project is built by netlify. Is there a way to fix this and if so why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it further I realized the issue was with netlify. I'm posting because I discovered a couple of things that could make building react projects with netlify a little bit complicated and I want others to be aware. ALWAYS change the build directory from public/ to build/ with a react application and make sure your build command is either `npm run build` or `CI=npm run buiild` or your production scripts will not be added to your main html file properly.